# Graph Theory (maybe related to handshake lemma?)

Tags: graph-theory

In Alaska there are three caves with $n$ bears in each of them. They are friendly bears, so every bear from any of the caves is on speaking terms with at least $n+1$ bears from the other two caves. Show that there are three bears, no two from the same cave, who are on speaking terms with each other.

I want to say that this is some version of the handshake lemma, but not sure where I want to start.

Comment: Are you familiar with Mantel's theorem?

Comment: Yes, I am somewhat familiar with it.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked a factor 3 on one side, that turned out to be rather important. I hope I withdrew my answer before anybody saw it :) Will try to come up with a better solution, but that will be tomorrow.

Comment: Are "schools" the same as "caves"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To simplify the exposition, I shall say that two bears from different caves are *friends* iff they are on speaking terms with each other. Assume that there is no three bears which are mutually friends. Choose a bear $b$ who has a maximal number $m$ of friends from one of the other two caves. Let $B$ denotes the bear $b$’s cave and $A$ denotes the cave with these $m$ friends of $b$. Let $c$ be a $b’$s friend from the cave $C$. Then $c$ can have at most $n-m$ friends in cave $A$. Therefore $c$  has at least $n+1-(n-m)=m+1$ friends in cave $B$, a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice, thank you.