# Tripartite n+1-regular graph containing a triangle

Tags: graph-theory, triangles

Suppose a tripartite, $(n+1)$-regular graph. Each one of its $3$ parts $(A,B,C)$ contains $n$ nodes. Show that the graph contains a triangle.

I think the fact that it is $n+1$ and not $n$ plays an important role because there will be at least an edge in both $B,C$ , let the edge `begins' from $A$.
I also tried to use the pigeonhole principle but I am lacking something. Any ideas?

Comment: Observation: We know that every part has $n \cdot (n+1)$ outgoing edges, hence it follows that there are exactly $n \cdot (n+1) / 2$ edges between any two parts.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058611/graph-theory-maybe-related-to-handshake-lemma) I answered positively a slightly stronger question.

Comment: @AlexRavsky They're the same question. No one is stronger than the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graph Theory (maybe related to handshake lemma?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058611/graph-theory-maybe-related-to-handshake-lemma)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $G$ does not contain a triangle.

Let $A,B,C$ the three partite sets.
Let $v$ be a vertex that maximizes the number of neighbours it has in one of the other partite sets (so no vertex have more neighbours in one single partite set than $v$).

By symmetry we may assume that $v\in A$, that $v$ has $k$ neighbours in $B$ and $k\geq\frac{n+1}2$.
Let $X=N(v)\cap B$ and $Y=N(v)\cap C$.

A vertex of $Y$ cannot have a neighbour in $X$ (that would complete a triangle with $v$),
so it has at most $n-k$ neighbours in $B$.
But then it must have $n+1-(n-k)=k+1$ neighbours in $A$, contradicting the choice of $v$. Contradiction.